# IntelliJ: jump to source via external URL?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to be able to click a source line in my code reviews, and have intellij open that file / line.  We use Phabracator for reviews, which has a setting specifically for this -- for example, one can use

```
txmt://open/?url=file:///Users/alincoln/editor_links/%r/%f&line=%l
```

to jump to source lines in TextMate. Is there an analogue for IntelliJ?

Comment: What is the format of one of the lines from your code review, can you post an example?

Comment: Can intellij open source files via link?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but if it's possible I'd like to know how - that's why I +1'ed your question :)

Comment: Maybe I'll write a plugin.  This is the doc for our [code review](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/external_editor/), though this question is more about intellij support than phabricator config.

Comment: Awesome. Please post back here if you make ground with the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: there is now a better option, explained in [Create a web browser link that opens a file in Intellij. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56061831/326106).

In Phabricator, under **Settings** -> **Display Preferences**, set **Editor Link** to

```
http://localhost:63343/api/file//path/to/source/%r/%f:%l
```

Replace `/path/to/source` with the actual path.

This works for me with PyCharm 2016.1.
Earlier versions used port 63342 instead of 63343.

**Update**: You may need to enable external connections and unsigned requests in IntelliJ's built-in server, as explained in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debugger.html#d1397508e188.
[image: Built-in server Settings]

Comment: Is there any documentation for this? I can't seem to get this to work and am generally interested in the API.