# Create a web browser link that opens a file in Intellij. Possible?

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea

Example, qbittorent can be made to open links that are of torrent files.

Email clients mailto:

Is it possible to create links in a browser that will open the given file in Intellij? (Not full path, but entire package possibly ).

Idea is that this will be created for bitbucket.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879) to add `idea://` protocol handler.

At the moment, it works on macOS only out of the box. For other platforms, you can try the [third-party solution](https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol) or other workarounds from the ticket comments.

---

There is also a built-in web server providing the [REST API to open files](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/a77365debaadcf00b888a977d89512f3f0f3cf9e/platform/built-in-server/src/org/jetbrains/ide/OpenFileHttpService.kt#L52).

It will work with the relative paths only when the IDE is already running and the project is open: `http://localhost:63342/api/file/relative/to/module/root/path/to/file.kt`.

Make sure to install [IDE Remote Control plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19991-ide-remote-control), this feature is no longer bundled.

---

With the [JetBrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) installed one will be able to use `jetbrains://` protocol for navigation, it's **work in progress** and should be available in **2019.2**.

See [JBProtocolNavigateCommand.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/navigation/JBProtocolNavigateCommand.kt) for the reference:

```
// handles URLs of the following types:

// jetbrains://idea/navigate/reference?project=IDEA
// [&reference[X]=com.intellij.navigation.JBProtocolNavigateCommand[.perform][#perform]]+
// [&path[X]=com/intellij/openapi/project/impl/JBProtocolNavigateCommand.kt[:23[:1]]]+
// [&selection[X]=25:5-26:6]+
```

Sample URL:

`jetbrains://idea/navigate/reference?project=IDEA&fqn=com.intellij.openapi.application.JetBrainsProtocolHandler#getParameters`

Toolbox URL matches regexp:

`"${JetBrainsProtocolHandler.PROTOCOL}([\\w\\-]+)/navigate/reference\\?project=(?<project>[\\w]+)(&fqn[\\d]*=(?<fqn>[\\w.\\-#]+))*(&path[\\d]*=(?<path>[\\w-_/\\\\.]+)(:(?<location1>[\\d]+))?(:(?<location2>[\\d]+))?)*(&selection[\\d]*=(?<line1>[\\d]+):(?<column1>[\\d]+)-(?<line2>[\\d]+):(?<column2>[\\d]+))*"`

There will be also UI for copying TBX protocol URLs directly from the editor similar to the **Copy Reference** action in the context menu. The same will work for IDE settings navigation.

Comment: issue number one. Relative path to module root might be a bit problematic. There should be a best match opener functionality. Not always you have the path or can figure it out properly, depending on where the project might on disc.

Comment: It should work like that in 2019.2 with the project reference and fqn. You don't have to specify the exact path, IDE will perform the search.

Comment: I am on mac. On 2019.2 now. Trying the various links. I Have a file in maven module relative to a workspace path/to/workspace/projects/myproject/src/main/java/my.package/MyClass.java 

Can you provide me with a full url example, because I am unable to get anything to open.

Comment: @momomo 2019.2 is not released yet.

Comment: The localhost approach does trigger intellij (albeit with constant popup annoyance about trusting unknown ... ) but doesn't open the relevant file.

Comment: I just had a request about updating to 2019.2 inside intellij.

Comment: @momomo please double check in Help | About, you've updated to 2019.1.2, not 2019.2.

Comment: Yes, you ar right. How about the old way? localhost approach ? also there is a Remote Call plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6027-remote-call as well. Does this do more or less the same thing?

Comment: Example for [this file](https://i.imgur.com/2PbO997.png) with the relative path `/src/main/java/de/mosst/labor/spring/boot/MainController.java` would be `http://localhost:63342/api/file/src/main/java/de/mosst/labor/spring/boot/MainController.java`. I'm not familiar with this plug-in, you can contact the developer for help, but it looks abandoned.

Comment: @momomo Enable [this option](https://i.imgur.com/rVvIkJs.png) to remove the warning popups.

Comment: It seems Toolbox App is released and we reached the 2019.2 version, so is there some comprehensive guide on how to use that `jetbrains://` protocol? I installed the Toolbox App, but the protocol still doesn't work (the example URL from this answer does nothing, failed to fetch). EDIT: Actually it does work when I open the URL in a new tab, but doesn't when I try to `fetch` it from JS. Still would like some docs on this feature

Comment: @mjs Please post your questions at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Answer (score 1):

As an update to @CrazyCoder's answer

This works* on Mac currently. (unable to test on anything else personally)

* There are some issues:

- There is no context menu option for generating this link from clicking on a line of code
- The keybinding (see below) generates the incorrect path, and it needs to be modified manually by either changing the sources root temporarily, or typing the missing path parts by hand.

There is a keybinding you can use to generate the url, under Preferences > Keymap > Copy Path/Reference > Toolbox URL. Note that the cursor location when using the keybinding matters. From what I can tell, if the cursor is at the beginning or end of a line, it generates a url with `&path=...`, else it generates with `&fqn=...`. The `fqn` option will often link to the wrong area of the code, especially when interfaces, libraries, auto-wiring, or anything not a direct vanilla class/object/function is attempted to link to.

I have filed an issue with more details on the broken path generated by the keybinding: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-290640

Answer (score -1):

I have created my custom (unofficial) "**jb://**" scheme, that can open file from the specified project.

I use it in the [git-mediawiki](https://gitlab.com/AndrewShark/git-mediawiki) project. After cloning the wiki page, I want to open it as a project in Writerside.

This is the URL example shown by `git-mediawiki` utility (I will place it in several lines to simplify reading):

```
jb://localhost?api=v1
&ide=writerside
&project_path=~/Documents/MediaWiki/
&file_path=wiki.blender.org/Building_Blender/Linux/Arch/Arch.mw
```

In this case, the `~/Documents/MediaWiki/` is a directory with the `.idea` folder. This is a multi-root project. The folder `~/Documents/MediaWiki/wiki.blender.org/Building_Blender/Linux/Arch/` contains a `.git` folder, and the `Arch.mw` is a file from that repo.

So after installing the `jb-url-handler` and clicking that link, the Writerside will open (if not yet), and the tab with file `Arch.mw` will be opened.

See https://github.com/Ashark/jb-url-handler.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)