# Rider/JetBrains IDE URL Scheme?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a utility - Chrome extension - that can open a file in Emacs and/or VSCode via a url scheme (i.e. `emacs://open?url=file:///Users/foo/bar.cs&line=25` or `vscode://file/Users/foo/bar.cs:25`)

Is such a thing possible with Rider? I have been unable to find anything to support this in the docs nor here on SO.

Comment: I think this answer will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066943/904679